# Django: Display DB data to only logged in users with multiple filters

Tags: django, django-views

I have a DB table as below.
[image]

**url to display DB data is**

```
url(r'^editinvoice/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.edit_invoice,name='editinvoice'),
```

**template.html code that redirects to this page is**

```
<a href="{% url "editinvoice" pk=invoices.id %}">{{ invoices.invoice_number }}</a></td>
```

`invoices.id` is foreign key of above DB table.

The link passes correct pk and details are correctly displayed. However if I just change the id in url, I can see information even if I am not the user related to it.
What should be done that information should be available to logged in user only if user if owner of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your views method `edit_invoice`, use `@login_required` decorator.
In the method you would raise 403 error:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def edit_invoice(request, pk):
    invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if invoice.user != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

See django docs about [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required).

Also see django doc about [PermissionDenied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view).

**Edit:**

Yea having a "does not exist" makes more sense. The most common one is to raise 404 exception, as if user is visiting a url that doesn't exist:

from django.http import Http404
raise Http404

[Django doc about Http404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).

Comment: I am using @login_required decorator. url to see details works only if user is logged in. But you as a user after login can see my details too.

Comment: I used permission Denied but now its working fine and user cannot see others invoice, however how to change default Django error and give a clean message like Invoice does not exist?

Comment: Edit my answer again.